# multi region deployment using terraform providers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've structured a `terraform` code to deploy different types of resources to a single `AWS` region. The code structure is like this:

```
- main.tf
- data.tf
- providers.tf
- variables.tf
- templates/
- modules/
  - module_main.tf
  - data.tf
  - variables.tf
  - modules/
    - sub_module_main.tf
    - data.tf
    - variables.f
```

So the idea is to create a group of resources with similar characteristics using the outer module. Then outer module uses the inner module for the same purpose.
Inside the inner module, it creates an S3 bucket. Now for each bucket inside the inner module I want to create a replication bucket in a different region. So the replication bucket is the only resource that I need to deploy in a second region. I read about having two aws providers and then pass specific provider to the module like:

```
module 'east' {
  source = ./..
  providers = {
    aws = aws.east
  }
  ...
}

module 'west' {
  source = ./..
  providers = {
    aws = aws.west
  }
  ...
}
```

But in my case I just want to deploy specific resources inside the module to both regions not the whole module. Given my code structure is it possible to handle this requirement using providers or any other method?

Comment: You can specify two different providers and on each resource specify explicitly which provider to use.

Comment: so for each resource inside the module I need to specify the provider? Can it use a default provider unless a different provider is explicitly specified?

Comment: I would probably restructure the code to move the multi-region resources into a separate module. Either that or you'll need to pass some extra parameter(s) into the module to control which resources get created.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your providers as follows to achieve your desired behavior:

```
#Standard AWS Provider Block:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "> 1.0"
    }
  }
}

#Define the default provider (no alias defined):

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "DEV"
}

#Define alternate aliased providers:

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "PROD"
  alias   = "prod"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-2"
  profile = "PROD-DR"
  alias   = "prod-dr"
}
```

With this configuration defined, a resource with no provider attribute defined will use the default provider. In the case above it will map to the profile DEV. Note that each profile you define in your tf files must be defined in your .aws/config and .aws/credentials files with the same profile name. To specify an alternate provider for a given resource use the provider attribute with the alias as the value in a resource definition:

```
provider = aws.prod-dr
```

This type of configuration will allow you to define multiple aws accounts and multiple regions and reference them interchangeably as needed.